# How get a data of a instance in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have the next problem when i intend get the data of a messageLogin but because this is a Instance dont be avaliable, but in the watch is avaliable to see the data. The question is how i can to access to this data for storage in a variable?
pst: the images show the content of a messageLogin

```
  Future handleSub(BuildContext context) async {
final Either<LoginMessageModel, JwtMessage> messageLogin =
    await blocLogin.handleSubmit();
    final msg = messageLogin.value.data[0].messages[0].message;
// final rta = messageLogin.fold((_l) => messageLogin, (r) => null);
print(messageLogin);
// showToast(context, messageLogin.value.jwt);
```

}

the error that give flutter is that:

The getter 'value' isn't defined for the type 'Either<LoginMessageModel, JwtMessage>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'value', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.

[Image of vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMdvX.png)

[Variable messageLogin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIuIq.png)

[Code that extract the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELrlL.png)

[Variable messageLogin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8tNw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s because the interface (or base class) `Either<T,K>` doesn’t have the `value` property but a concrete has it instead.

Based on your screenshots I can see that it is an instance of `LoginMessageModel` so you have two solutions:

1. Move the `value` to the base class having in mind that all the inherited will access that property;
2. Cast the object `(messageLogin as LoginMessageModel).value...` so you can get rid of the warning and explicitly assume the type there;